# How to make the two important years 1492 and 1969 with a minimum number of 1s

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Using only 1s, make 1492 and 1969 with the minimum number of digits

Rules:
allowed operations +, -, ×, ÷, ^, (), and ! (factorial).
Concatenation of the original digits is allowed, but not (1+1)1=21.
Note, the () can also be used as binomial coefficient. 
Example: $\binom{11}{1+1}+1111^{11} +(11+1)!$
The record to beat is 13 for both!

Comment: no square roots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

11 for 1492:

> $(((1+1+1)!)!+(11+1+1)\times(1+1))\times(1+1)$
>  $=(6!+26)\times2$
>  $=746\times2$
>  $=1492$

10 for 1969:

> $(\frac{((1+1+1)!)!}{1+1+1+1}-1)\times11$
>  $=(\frac{720}{4}-1)\times11$
>  $=179\times11$
>  $=1969$